# Strings and files

Tags: c, string, file

I need help on a C program I'm writing. The goal is to find the number of times a substring occurs in a file. The user enters the substring and the name of the file. There is case sensitivity, if the string is "the" it will only count the number of times "the" is in the file, not "THE" or "The". Each line of the file won't be longer than 250 characters. We have to use strcmp and fgets, no strstr allowed.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINELENGTH 250
#define STRINGLENGTH 100

int main ()
{
    int count = 0;
    FILE *stringFilePtr = NULL;
    char *filename[30];
    char line[LINELENGTH];
    char string[STRINGLENGTH];
    int length = STRINGLENGTH;

    printf ("Enter the string you want to search for:\n");
    fgets (string, STRINGLENGTH, stdin);

    printf ("Enter the name of the file you want to search through:\n");
    scanf ("%s", filename);
    stringFilePtr = fopen (filename, "r");

    if (stringFilePtr != NULL) {
        while (fgets (line, length, stringFilePtr) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp (line, string) == 0);
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        fclose (stringFilePtr);
    }
    else {
        printf ("The file %s was unable to open.", filename);
    }

    printf
        ("There were %d occurrences of the string %s within the file %s.\n",
        count, string, filename);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: 1) `line` includes newline. 2) `count` is uninitialized. 3) `fclose(stringFilePtr);` move into if-block from else-block. 4) Probably the `line` needs to be split by blank space etc.

Comment: You don't handle the condition where the string occurs multiple times on the same line.

Comment: You have not specify if every line contains only one word or not, or I am missing something?

Comment: You say, "There is no case sensitivity" but then describe case-sensitive behaviour... either you made a typo, or you've mixed up the definitions of "case sensitive" and "case insensitive".

Comment: `strcmp()` compares one entire string to another... it doesn't match when one simply contains the other.  Not only are you comparing entire lines to the string from the user, but you've stripped the newline from the one the user enters and not from the line from the file, so you won't even match an entire line.

Comment: you will find `strstr` useful

Comment: You're right @Dmitri, I meant there is case sensitivity. I see what you mean about stripping the newline as well, I can't see why I did that and will remove it. We are given sample files, such as the US Constitution and we have to find the number of times "United States" occurs in the document(twice), but my program returns 405 occurrences.

Comment: for a start you need to set count = 0 at the beginning

Comment: How can I account for when the character occurs multiple times on the same line?

Comment: `Ints are initialized to 0 automatically in C.`Famous last words.ATH0!45#67(&%#$

Comment: Hmmm.... You want to count occurrences of the string `"United States"` in a file, yet `STRINGLENGTH` is `10`. More generous array sizes may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of potential pitfalls in your code that may surprise you. You avoid one by prompting for `string` before `filename`, however if that were reversed, you would have left a `'\n'` in the *input buffer* (e.g. `stdin`) which your next call to `fgets` would happily accept as an *empty line*. When mixing input between the `scanf` family of functions and `fgets`, you must always account for any characters left in the input buffer. (you can do this in a simple loop and also with careful choice of your format string (e.g. `" %[^\n]%*c"`).

Next, while `STRINGLENGTH` of `100` is completely up to you, it's worth noting the longest word in the unabridged dictionary is `27-characters` long making `28-chars` adequate for any known defined word.

When reading the file, why read one-line-at-a-time, when you want to compare one-word-at-a-time? `fscanf` will happily read each word, one-by-one throughout the whole file and it will skip any *whitespace* (e.g. `'\n'`) before reading the next word, even if it begins on the next line. This will also help you avoid having to check for, and remove, all `'\n'`s before making your search term comparison. (example of how to remove `'\n'` from end of line is shown with `string` below)

Next, ALWAYS validate ALL user input, file openings and memory allocations. With that in mind, it appears you were attempting something similar to the following, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRINGLENGTH 28  /* longest word in unabridged dictionary is 27-chars */

#ifndef _POSIX_PATH_MAX
#define _POSIX_PATH_MAX 4096
#endif

#define PATH_MAX _POSIX_PATH_MAX

int main (void)
{
    int count = 0;
    char filename[PATH_MAX] = "",
        word[STRINGLENGTH] = "",
        string[STRINGLENGTH] = "";
    size_t len = 0;
    FILE *stringFilePtr = NULL;

    printf ("Enter filename: ");    /* validate ALL input */
    if (scanf ("%s", filename) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - filename.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* empty any chars (e.g. '\n') that remain in stdin */
    for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}

    /* open & validate file open for reading */
    if (!(stringFilePtr = fopen (filename, "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n.", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter search string: ");
    if (!fgets (string, STRINGLENGTH, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input\n.");
        return 1;
    }

    len = strlen (string);          /* get string length */
    if (string[len - 1] == '\n')    /* check for trailing '\n' */
        string[--len] = 0;          /* overwrite with nul-byte */

    while (fscanf (stringFilePtr, " %s", word) == 1)
        if (strcmp (word, string) == 0)
            ++count;

    fclose (stringFilePtr);

    printf ("There are '%d' occurrences of '%s' within file '%s'.\n",
        count, string, filename);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/damages.txt
Personal injury damage awards are unliquidated
and are not capable of certain measurement; thus, the
jury has broad discretion in assessing the amount of
damages in a personal injury case. Yet, at the same
time, a factual sufficiency review insures that the
evidence supports the jury's award; and, although
difficult, the law requires appellate courts to conduct
factual sufficiency reviews on damage awards in
personal injury cases. Thus, while a jury has latitude in
assessing intangible damages in personal injury cases,
a jury's damage award does not escape the scrutiny of
appellate review.

Because Texas law applies no physical manifestation
rule to restrict wrongful death recoveries, a
trial court in a death case is prudent when it chooses
to submit the issues of mental anguish and loss of
society and companionship. While there is a
presumption of mental anguish for the wrongful death
beneficiary, the Texas Supreme Court has not indicated
that reviewing courts should presume that the mental
anguish is sufficient to support a large award. Testimony
that proves the beneficiary suffered severe mental
anguish or severe grief should be a significant and
sometimes determining factor in a factual sufficiency
analysis of large non-pecuniary damage awards.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/srchinfile
Enter filename: ../dat/damages.txt
Enter search string: the
There are '12' occurrences of 'the' within file '../dat/damages.txt'.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.